# Array compare, school task doesn't work

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

First post here so tell me if I did something wrong :)

So I have this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //declaring first array
        Console.Write("Enter the size of the first the array: ");
        int sizeOne = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[]firstArray = new int[sizeOne];

        //fill it from console
        for (int counter = 0; counter<=sizeOne - 1; counter++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a value: ");
            firstArray[counter] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //for test
            // Console.WriteLine(firstArray[counter]);
        }

        //declaring second array
        Console.Write("Enter the size of the second array: ");
        int sizeTwo = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] secondArray = new int[sizeTwo];

        //fill it from console
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= sizeTwo - 1; counter++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a value: ");
            firstArray[counter] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //for test
            // Console.WriteLine(secondArray[counter]);
        }

        //compare size and values, as sidenote it could write not equal even 
        //when the user inputs two arrays with different lengths to save time :)
        if (firstArray.Length == secondArray.Length)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= sizeOne; counter++)
            {
                if ((firstArray[counter]) != (secondArray[counter]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The two arrays aren't equal");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The two arrays are equal");                        
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The two arrays aren't equal");
        }
    }
```

It should compare the arrays by length, and elements. It does if two arrays have different length but at equal number of elements it always writes not equal. What did I miss?

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: Arrays are zero based. You should never allow your index to reach the length of the array. Always < array.Length

Comment: I modified the code a bit. Now it writes that the two arrays are equal and not equal in the same time...

Comment: The other problem (but secondary in this context) is the fact that you are too trusting of the user inputs. If your user types anything but a number the code will crash at each Int32.Parse. You should make yourself confortable in using Int32.TryParse

Comment: Fair points. Usually I use (int counter = 0; variable - 1; counter++). I guess that's a bad habit. About second right I was lazy to use TryParse

Comment: Probably is a bit early but if you use Linq and generic List a lot of this code will disappear

Comment: Yes that's true I found a solution with Linq but hey I only started coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo, or copy-paste error, whatever you want to call it.  In your 2nd loop, when you are supposed to populate `secondArray`, you are populating `firstArray` by mistake. This means that `secondArray` only ever has zeroes. You probably got lucky (or unlucky) that `firstArray` was always equal or larger in size than `secondArray`. Otherwise you would have gotten an exception, which may have helped you to spot your mistake.

Note that once you fix it, you will also get an out of bounds exception, because your comparing loop uses the `counter <= sizeOne` condition, which is wrong.  It should be `counter < sizeOne`, otherwise you will go past the end of the array.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the loop a bit:
You need a Boolean flag, that indicates if there are mismatches. Otherwise it would print "The two arrays are equal" if just the first element(s) matches.

```
if (firstArray.Length == secondArray.Length)
{
    bool areEqual = true;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < firstArray.Length; counter++)
    {
        if ((firstArray[counter]) != (secondArray[counter]))
        {
            areEqual = false;
            //Console.WriteLine("The two arrays aren't equal");
            break;
        }
        // This would get executed if the first elements are equal, but others are not
        //else
        //{
        //  Console.WriteLine("The two arrays are equal");                        
        //}
    }

    if (areEqual)
       Console.WriteLine("The two arrays are equal"); 
    else 
       Console.WriteLine("The two arrays aren't equal");
}
```

And then there is of course a build in function (in .NET) called `SequenceEqual` that does compare two arrays:

```
using System.Linq;    
...
bool areEqual = firstArray.SequenceEqual(secondArray);
if (areEqual)
   Console.WriteLine("The two arrays are equal"); 
else 
   Console.WriteLine("The two arrays aren't equal");
```

[See NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XqFdCq)

There is also a Typo: You're filling the firstArray twice.

```
    //fill it from console
    for (int counter = 0; counter <= sizeTwo - 1; counter++)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a value: ");
        // **Must be secondArray**
        firstArray[counter] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //for test
        // Console.WriteLine(secondArray[counter]);
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand why my code is wrong. I check first length if same  
Do Stuff else write out arrays aren't equal.

At Do Stuff part I tried to wrote that at first mismatching element write out arrays aren't equal and break the loop.

If the loop ends without break then write out that arrays are equal.

Comment: Well I guess your solution is just easier :).

Comment: Found a typo, should work now :)

Comment: So many error in a simple code... Typo fixed, I read about SequenceEqual but I don't want to cheat with methods as I try to get comfortable with arrays.  First steps.. :).

Comment: Good idea to first code it yourself a few times before you use something like sequenceequals.